# need SQL help in finding pairs of values that don't exist in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, set-theory

The table my_table has a bunch of columns, but the only two I really care about are [timestamp (5 min increments), id]

for example

| timestamp | id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-02 03:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-03-02 03:05:00 | 1 |
| 2022-03-02 03:00:00 | 2 |
| 2022-03-02 03:05:00 | 2 |
| 2022-03-02 03:00:00 | 3 |
| 2022-03-02 03:00:00 | 4 |
| 2022-03-02 03:05:00 | 4 |
| 2022-03-02 03:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-03-02 03:05:00 | 5 |

Now, as you may notice, the pair
| 2022-03-02 03:05:00 | 3  |
is missing. **This is the scenario I want to return the missing pair for**. For every timestamp in a given range of values I'm interested in, I want to find, if it has a corresponding id. the id's are all in the list (1,2,3,4,5).

I tried the following:

```
select * 
       from 
       (select distinct timestamp from my_table) 
       as a  
       left join (select timestamp, id from my_table) 
       as b 
       on a.timestamp=b.timestamp 
where id is null;
```

I thought that this would find what i was looking for, but alas the pair values I am looking for don't exist in the given table so they don't show up in the join. My other idea is to create a temp table with all the timestamp values in a certain range pair with each id, so 5 pairs for every timestamp, and then outer join that with my original table to find null values, but I'm not sure how to create such a temp table.

Any ideas?

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_, and a part of `select distinct`. Simply write `select distinct timestamp from my_table` to make code clearer.

Comment: So what do you want as results?

Comment: @Stu I want the pairs of (timestamp, id) that are missing. each id should go with each timestamp, and if it doesn't, i want it returned

Comment: you can't select a row that's not there, so you have to infer the data. So for id 3, how do I know what the missing timestamp is - are they always either 00:00 or 05:00?

Comment: @stu Yes they are always ending in 00:00 or 05:00. i will have a range of 2 hours for timestamps im interested in, so 24 timestamp values because the timestamps are five min increments. example the range could be (2022-03-01 03:00:00 to 2022-03-01 03:00:00)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create tally tables.  There are plenty of posts in the googleshpere depending on your flavour of SQL.  Create one for all the time periods you are interested in and one for your IDs.  CROSS JOIN to create a table of all the possible values and then LEFT JOIN your source table and apply a WHERE clause to filter out any records where your source table has been found.  The resulting data set is every 'missing' record.

Comment: i should clarify that the real values for ID are not 1,2,3,4,5 they are char strings but I changed the values to not reveal any real data

Comment: Perhaps you should mention `EXCEPT` to subtract result sets. That would make the answer more complete and useful.

Comment: you could use an EXCEPT but means the two queries have to return the same colum names and data types.  A LEFT JOIN and filter where joined table is not found gives you more flexibility of the data returned.

Comment: @AaronReese thank you the cross join worked!